# Google Sheets: What's a way to concatenate strings in the same way as SUMIFS adds numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation

I have Google Sheet that contains on each line job data like: date, quote number, street address, suburb, contractor, price etc

I can summarise daily sales using a SUMIFS() function, like:
=sumifs(JobTotalPrice, Contractor, C58, WeekOf, B58, DayOfWeek, D58)

...but I'd like to concatenate, for each day, a summary of the jobs done in the form of the quote number and suburb, ideally like:
 "Q8374 Epsom, Q8388 Mt Wellington" etc.

Is this possible with a spreadsheet formula or will I need Apps Scripts?

Example data and desired result:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12JM4c4E55CKQnS20A4gTOMsMXAxPhB6bRHQ7jImJCmA/edit#gid=0

The solution (not using the sample sheet but the real sheet):

```
=JOIN(", ", ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(QuoteNum, Contractor = C61, WeekOf = B61, PmtPeriod = D61) & " " & FILTER(Suburb, Contractor = C61, WeekOf = B61, PmtPeriod = D61)))
```

...which looks like this:
3588 Mt Eden, 3550 Epsom, 3585 Mt Roskill

Comment: I want to help with it, and I think already know how to, but would be nice to receive a link to example sheet

Comment: Good idea! Example sheet link added, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Aurielle, nice skills!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can unique the day of the week list using:

```
=UNIQUE(D3:D)
```

then use that to join your data by including this formula to the right of it:

```
=join(",",ARRAYFORMULA(filter(B:B,D:D=$G3)&" "&filter(C:C,D:D=$G3)))
```

[image]

Comment: a very nice formula, and much shorter than my, I'll use it in future, but doesn't work by question criteria, if you have same "Suburb" appears more than once in same "day of week" (can be different dates), it doesn't sums "Quote Num", but returns several times in same concatination line.

Comment: My understanding of the question he was asking, was that he just wanted to summarize

Comment: I used a modified version of your function, as pasted in the question post. Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 0):

I made use of query function:

```
=IFERROR(MID(CONCATENATE(QUERY($A$2:$E,"select ', ',SUM(B),' ',C where(D = '"&I2&"') group by (C)",-1)),18,LEN(CONCATENATE(QUERY($A$2:$E,"select ', ',SUM(B),' ',C where(D = '"&I2&"') group by (C)",-1)))),IFERROR(1/0))
```

[Here is my example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1beDtMtKtN15h5AuSRPAFn0UflMKWrEpwkmbU1CNngtQ/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Aurielle's was the cleaner choice in this case.